# CORS policy Error with Bearer Token Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, bearer-token

I am building a react application postAPI using bearer token.

I already stored bearer token in localStorage and try to receive data for below code.

However, it is returning me CORS policy error. I am able to receive data from postman using Authorization tab. It is not working for a Header tab along with Authorization Bearer token though.

Could you help me how I can resolve this issue? I usually open cors policy from the server, but this is actually from a third party api.

I have tried no-cors, but you can't send headers with no-cors mode.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://d9u7x85vp9.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/engine' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.


const postAIMove = async () => {

    const fetchOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: "include",
        headers: { 
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("authToken")}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({board})
    }



  const res = await fetch(`${API_URI}/engine`, fetchOptions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is about browser security. A request in postman works, because postman ignores invalid `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.

You need to add your host `http://localhost:3000` to the list of allowed hosts for that resource. This can only be done if you have control over the configuration of the webserver.

Comment: Can it be done by adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000" in the headers?

Comment: I believe you need to add the protocol as well (`http://`)

Comment: Sorry I tried adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000", but not working.

Comment: Are you adding this on the client-side (in your above code) or on the server-side? Because it will only affect anything if the server sets this as a response header.

Comment: I realized this third party api has dev server for the localhost cors. Thank you so much for your help guys